# Dominating queens

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

A queen dominates any square on a chessboard in the same row, column, or diagonal as the queen. How few queens can dominate all squares on an 8 by 8 chessboard?

I don't know how to start. Thanks

Comment: I thought I had accidentally switched to a kinky website after reading the title :).

Comment: At least you know that it is less than 8, which narrows things down.

Answer (score 0):

since I can't comment [no rep points] here's what I found [as an answer]
the answer is 5, [many solutions] and to prove 4 or less is not possible see:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30330/is-there-a-good-argument-for-why-you-cant-place-4-queens-which-cover-a-chessboa

it says essentially that you have to try all possibilities and none of them works... So mathematically it's interesting because it's harder than it seems to come up with a nice mathematical proof.
HTH